# Imagemagick / ghostscript add crop marks to pdf

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I have a multipage pdf that I need to add trim marks onto, ideally using ghostscript, imagemagick or a linux based tool.

I am using the below command and this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8osEo.jpg) as an overlay:

```
composite -gravity center -density 300 -quality 100 page.pdf crop.png out.pdf
```

I have it working fine for single page pdfs however I need this overlay applied to each page in the file, any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to extent the PDF pages to the same size as the trim-mark template image.

```
  TEMPLATE_SIZE=$(identify -format '%wx%h' crop.png)
  convert \( -density 300 page.pdf -extent $TEMPLATE_SIZE \) null: \
          crop.png -gravity center -compose multiply -layers composite \
          out.pdf
```